# mlr3 - how to remove incomplete observations using `mlr3` interface

Tags: r, mlr3

Is it possible to remove incomplete observation within a task --- `task <- TaskRegr$new("data", data, "y")`  --- using `mlr3` filters or pipeops?

Comment: The new pipeop [`PipeOpFilterRows`](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3pipelines/pull/410) will be able to perform the requested behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a preprocessing operator for removing observations.

What I would do is to use `filter` method within a Task.

Example:

```
t = tsk("pima")
ids = complete.cases(t$data())

# number of incomplete observations
sum(!ids)

t$filter(which(ids))

# number of incomplete observations
# should be zero now
ids = complete.cases(t$data())
sum(!ids)
```

`complete.cases` gives a Boolean vector that indicates which rows contain complete observations (no NA's).
`filter` subsets task's data by row ids provided in the parameter. Row ids not given in the parameter are removed in-place.

If you want to instead impute incomplete observations, there are a few imputation operators like PipeOpImputeConstant that impute features by a constant.